# Why can traits in scala.collection create an instance?

Tags: scala, collections

I am trying the following code in Scala, which is coming from [An Overview of the Collections API](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html).

```
import collection._
scala> Traversable(1, 2, 3)
res5: Traversable[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
scala> Iterable("x", "y", "z")
res6: Iterable[String] = List(x, y, z)
scala> Map("x" -> 24, "y" -> 25, "z" -> 26)
res7: scala.collection.Map[String,Int] = Map(x -> 24, y -> 25, z -> 26)
scala> SortedSet("hello", "world")
res9: scala.collection.SortedSet[String] = TreeSet(hello, world)
scala> IndexedSeq(1.0, 2.0)
res11: IndexedSeq[Double] = Vector(1.0, 2.0)
```

The result shows that those trait can all call its `apply` method to create an instance of its implementation. But after looking for `scala.collection.package` object, I found nothing. I think there must be somewhere that binds those trait to its subclass and imports to my program. Can someone explain where it is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling `apply` on the trait's companion object, not on the trait.

For example, `Traversable`:

- [The trait](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Traversable)
- [The object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Traversable$)

If you click on `apply` in the companion object's scaladoc, you can see that the `Traversable` object inherits its apply method from [`GenericCompanion`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion), which has a link to the [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/collection/generic/GenericCompanion.scala#L1) so you can see how it's implemented.

Comment: but there is not `apply` method in the companion object of Traversable?

Comment: There is. Look at [the second link](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Traversable$). It's the second item listed in the "Value Members" section.

Comment: oh, I see. The `apply` method is extends from `TraversableFactory`.

Comment: If you click on `apply`, you can see that the `Traversable` object inherits its `apply` method from [`GenericCompanion`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion), which has a link to the [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/collection/generic/GenericCompanion.scala#L1) so you can see how it's implemented.